# How do I use nameref's label with addcontentsline

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, errors

I am trying to use the `nameref` `\label` functionality alongside the use of `\addcontentsline` that creates invisible sections and subsections that appear in the `\tableofcontents`.

The commands can be seen below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}% Add section to ToC
  \label{sec:\thesection}
}
\newcommand{\fakesubsection}[1]{%
  \par\refstepcounter{subsection}% Increase subsection counter
   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}% Add subsection to ToC
   \label{subsec:\thesubsection}
}
\begin{document}


\fakesection{Fs}
\fakesubsection{s}
\nameref{sec:\thesection}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to do this there is no output! Blank page.

Comment: Using the `article` class it works fine. Which class are you using?

Comment: @LudovicC. Please see the revised code. It's the call to `fullref` that breaks -- I'm calling `fullref` since what I want is the full name of the section and subsection.

Comment: Is the output what you want if you load also the `fancyref` package?

Comment: @LudovicC. I accidentally put in `fullref` what I actually wanted was `nameref`.

Comment: And then with `nameref` the output is not what you want since it takes the previous label and not the one defined in your command. Am I right?

Comment: @LudovicC. Well i tried calling it after defining an invisible heading a few times and it keeps failing me

Comment: Simple question but what is your aim with that because having invisible sections to which you can refer and appearing in the ToC does not seem to be really common...?

Comment: @LudoVicC. I am making far from a normal document. It is part of our internal reporting that has highly specialised, industry specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to teach `nameref` what's the title.

I modified your approach, as assigning automatically a label doesn't make much sense, because you *won't* be able to know what number to use (unless your document have a really strict format). Do as you prefer, adding `\label` in the definitions is just what's needed to go to your approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  % go to vertical mode and don't allow a page break here
  \par\nopagebreak
  % step up the counter
  \refstepcounter{section}
  % teach nameref the title
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}
  % add to TOC
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}
}
\newcommand{\fakesubsection}[1]{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \refstepcounter{subsection}
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section just for testing}\label{ts}

Here is the title: \nameref{ts}.

\fakesection{A fake section}\label{Fs}
\fakesubsection{A fake subsection}\label{s}

Here is the title of the fake section: \nameref{Fs}

Here is the title of the fake subsection: \nameref{s}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the redefinition of `\label` inside `nameref`. You have to fake the label setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fakesection[1]{{%
  \let\newlabel\relax
  \par\refstepcounter{section}%
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{\newlabel{sec:\thesection}{{\thesection}{\arabic{page}}{#1}{}{}}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}% Add section to ToC
}}
\newcommand\fakesubsection[1]{{%
  \let\newlabel\relax
  \par\refstepcounter{subsection}% Increase subsection counter
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{\newlabel{subsec:\thesubsection}{{\thesubsection}{\arabic{page}}{#1}{}{}}}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}% Add subsection to ToC
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\fakesection{foo}
\fakesubsection{bar}

\section{baz}\label{sec:bazzz}

\nameref{sec:1}
\nameref{subsec:1.1}
\nameref{sec:bazzz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to add a `\phantomsection` with these commands to get the link to go to the right place?

Comment: I have no links ...

Comment: If you load the `hyperref` package you will have a link for the baz reference but not for the two other ones... Do you have a work around for that?

Comment: There is no target for the fakesection/subsection, so where should the link point to??

Comment: Where the fakesection/subsection are called in the document?

Comment: makes no sense to me